# How to make a second list populate after a you select an item in the first list preferably from a data base/excell

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

This is a pretty specific question that I hope I can get some insight to. I don't have any code on this part yet mainly because I'm not sure where to start.

There is a supervisor drop down and an agent drop down. The way I need it to work is that once you select a supervisor the corresponding agents will populate in the agent drop down. There are thousands of agents so it would take some time to actually go through and type them all out. We have a data base that populates and sorts the data automatically. Is there a way to code this so that A list you select from basically generates a second drop down list?

Thank you for any help in advance and sorry for the lack of code. I tried to research but I am coming up empty handed.

*edit, this is what I got after connecting to the server. It gives me the drop down for the supervisor but I am really lost at generating the list of agents that correlate with that supervisor. Ill continue to research what was said about ajax and json. But if someone can help me better understand that would be awesome, I cant find really any tutorials with MSSQL, only documentation.

```
$sql = "SELECT Supervisor FROM [tbl_Intake_SupervisorProfile]";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

    echo"<Select Supervisoer='Supervisor'>";

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['Supervisor'] . "'>" . $row['Supervisor'] . "</option>";
}

    echo"</select>";

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);


?>
```

Comment: Mind sharing what you already have?

Comment: Simple: 1) on supervisor select "change" event,  AJAX your backend API like `getAgents.php?q=superTrooper` 2) backend responds with a JSON list 3) query your DB agents **table** where an agent's **supervisor** matches the `$_GET["q"]` query. 4)  Inside the success callback clear the *Agents* select (from previous option elements) and create `option` element by looping the returned JSON.

Comment: What I already have is extremely basic. Its just a list option with a drop down and some CSS styling so. I just wanted to know what direction to take and Roko, your response definitely makes sense. I am not too knowledgeable with AJAX and JSON but I will look into it further and see what I come up with. Overall it seems like that is what I am looking for. If I have further questions when I write the code ill post them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$("#supervisor").on("change", populateAgents);
```

where the `populateAgents` function should be something like:

```
function populateAgents () {
   $.getJSON("getAgents.php", {supervisor: this.value}, function( agentsData ) {
       console.log( agentsData ); // test response
       // loop agents data and insert <option> elements into #agents 
   });
}
```

where in **getAgents.php** you'd have something like:

```
<?php

    // WARNING! This is a pseudo-demo!
    // Always sanitize (filter_var) your inputs and DB queries using PDO or such

    if ( isset($_GET["supervisor"])) {
       // SELECT * FROM agents WHERE supervisor = $_GET["supervisor"]
       // Than, after you build your $agentsArray
       echo json_encode($agentsArray);
       exit;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I am currently looking up AJAX and JSOM to familiarize myself with this code. Once I have a better understanding of the two I will come back and reference this!

Comment: What is that bottom code specifically doing? 

I get that its retrieving the information and then its producing it with the echo but how does it get called in my PHP file. This should be getting called with the jquery function but when i put it all together its not working.. I understand at least what is happening but not sure how to tie it all together. More specifically the agents array, its giving me an undefined variable and I am not 100% on where to define this

Comment: @Malsum Above the PHP's `echo` you can find two comment lines. What those are saying is - that you need to create somehow your `$agentsArray` by querying your SQL database. Using JS and AJAX you passed to PHP a value inside the `$_GET["supervisor"]`. If in your database you have a table `agents` with rows like: `id:0; name:"someAgentName"; supervisor:"supervisorName"` - Now, if you use a SQL query like `SELECT * FROM agents WHERE supervisor = $_GET["supervisor"]` the database will return a filtered array of agents.

Comment: Since jQuery's `.getJSON()` expects a JSON response, you can use PHP's `json_encode()`. So PHP will `ECHO` that JSON and as such will be returned to JS. You should than see in console such JSON response thanks to `console.log( agentsData );` . From that point - on you can do whatever you want in JS with `agentsData` Array objects. Like create a UI table, create option dropdown elements, etc.

Comment: I cant thank you enough for all the help. I am going to give this a shot today and see if I can get it down!

Comment: Okay so I am right on the edge of getting this to work however I am getting this odd error of trying to get property of a non object using 

$rowcount=$query->num_rows;

I am trying to get this based of their supervisor so if supervisor = agent then select them... I don't have any unique identifiers other then the agents ID. Everything else I think I am doing correct.

Comment: its specifically with this code

$rowcount=$query->num_rows;


 if($rowcount>0)
 {
  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))

Comment: Nevermind I actually figured it out. I guess there was an issue with my SQL syntax in the PHP. I was using "where supervisor = $supervisor and I changed it to like instead of equals and it works perfectly! Thank you again for all your help!

Comment: @Malsum really glad you made it! I can feel your power of victory :)